# Algorithm to slide vector across a vector

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, matrix

I've been asking questions about Matrices, and splitting them up into blocks - But that clearly isn't working so I'm taking another route.

Let's say in this example I have a Matrix (vector) that is 4x4:

M1 =

```
    0 1 0 1
    1 1 1 0
    0 0 0 1
    0 1 1 1
```

M2 =

```
   0 1
   1 0
```

Now, I need to identify which block in M1 best fits the one in M2. So basically, identifying a small matrix inside a big matrix.

The algorithm I need help with is basically sliding the small matrix across Matrix 1 until it's found it's best fit or match. (I am using Correlation / Similarity measures)

I've been thinking it will need to slide at one pixel/value at one time. But, obviously I don't want to check the correlation on each value.

Here is the function for comparing the matrix1 (at the current position) to matrix 2:

This is the function that compares the matrix:

```
   bool compareMatrix(vector<double> &theMatrix1, vector<double> &theMatrix2, int 
   startRow, int startCol)
   {
      cout << theMatrix1[startRow*4+startCol]; // This prints out the particular block
   }
```

Now what I was thinking was making a temp vector that stores the values of matrix1 (at the current position) and then the values of matrix1 (at the current position) would then be pushed inside the temp vector, this temp vector would then be passed to the correlation function which would then return a value.

My question is: How would I push the contents of "theMatrix1[startRow*4+startCol]" to a temp vector?

So for example (This wouldn't work):

```
vector<double> temp(2*2, 0);
temp.push_back(theMatrix1[startRow*4+startCol]);

double corr = correlation(temp, matrix2, 4, 4); 
return corr;
```

I hope I've explained enough (Note: This is different from previous posts).

Hope someone can help,

Thanks :)

Comment: this question looks familiar...

Comment: This question is about inserting values inside a temp vector and then handling the data, rather than splitting into blocks.. It scans the image :)

Comment: you should search M1 by M2 .and this order is O(size_m1 * size_m2). when you search M1 for each block calculate an error of matching(this is show how many of element in M1 is not matching with M2)and find minimum error of matching numbers.

Comment: Hey - Thanks for your reply. The problem is that I'm having problems actually scanning M1 to even consider searching the contents of M2..

Answer (score 1):

One way of scanning one object across another is to reverse the one object (h'(x, y) = h(-x, -y). and then to use the convolution theorem - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_theorem and see http://www-structmed.cimr.cam.ac.uk/Course/Convolution/convolution.html for something that works in two dimensions. The point about the convolution theorem is that doing an FFT is only n log n, so for some parameters it is a lot faster.

The fact that this is widely used in signal processing also suggests to me that if you really need correlation, you will not find any shortcuts mcuh faster than this. If you are satisfied with missing stuff some of the time, perhaps you could do something like looking for features in both matrices, find matches of features, and then check the alignments suggested by those matches.